# How to make overflow:scroll with dynamic height

Tags: html, css

How to make overflow:scroll with dynamic height for example below, without flex/grid/vh?
Problem is, that all content must fit screen(must see footer), and longlist dynamicaly ajust to screen height. Without height overflow:scroll not work, but setting it to 100% making it height as parent and content overflow down with height from header and footer.
Basically i want to .header .longlist and .footer fit .content height without overflow by ajusting .longlist height with .content height changes.

```
<style>
    .content {}

    .longlist {}

    .header {}

    .footer {}
</style>

<body>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="header">Header</div>
        <div class="longlist">
            <div>1</div>
            <div>1</div>
            <div>1</div>
            ...
        </div>
        <div class="footer">Footer</div>
    </div>

</body>
```

Comment: I created a demo, I didn't clearly understand [check this once](https://www.codeply.com/p/r9FismPfKr)

Comment: Please clearify your question since you seem to want both: the content always to be visible but also to have overflow.

Comment: @biberman Must be visible header and footer, but longlist scrollable via overflow:scroll;

Comment: Why "*without flex/grid/vh*"?

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare header and footer as `position: fixed` and give the longlist the same margin-top like the height of the header for not hiding the first div in the longlist, which gets the `overflow-y: scroll`. Add a background color to both, header and footer, for not beeing transparent.

```css
html,
body {
    height: 100%;
}

.header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: white;
}
.longlist {
    margin-top: 20px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

.footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
    <div class="header">Header</div>
    <div class="longlist">
        <div>1</div>
        <div>1</div>
        <div>1</div>
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="footer">Footer</div>
</div>
```

To show the scroll effect here a **Working example** (with a looong list of divs):

```css
html,
body {
    height: 100%;
}

.header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: white;
}
.longlist {
    margin-top: 20px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

.footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
    <div class="header">Header</div>
    <div class="longlist">
        <div>1</div>
        <div>1</div>
        <div>1</div>
        <div>1</div>
        <div>1</div>
        <div>1</div>
        <div>1</div>
        <div>1</div>
        <div>1</div>
        <div>1</div>
        <div>1</div>
        <div>1</div>
        <div>1</div>
        <div>1</div>
        <div>1</div>
        <div>1</div>
        <div>1</div>
        <div>1</div>
        <div>1</div>
        <div>1</div>
        <div>1</div>
        <div>1</div>
        <div>1</div>
        <div>1</div>
        <div>1</div>
        <div>1</div>
        <div>1</div>
        <div>1</div>
        <div>1</div>
        <div>1</div>
        <div>1</div>
        <div>1</div>
        <div>1</div>
        <div>1</div>
        <div>1</div>
        <div>1</div>
        <div>1</div>
        <div>1</div>
        <div>1</div>
        <div>1</div>
        <div>1</div>
        <div>1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">Footer</div>
</div>
```